# Don't understand efficiency is different in foldLeft and foldRight in Scala

Tags: scala, fold

Read the following paragraph in Programming in Scala, 2nd Edition that didn't make sense to me.

```
def flattenLeft[T](xss: List[List[T]]) =
  (List[T]() /: xss) (_ ::: _)

def flattenRight[T](xss: List[List[T]]) =
  (xss :\ List[T]()) (_ ::: _)
```

> Because list concatenation, `xs ::: ys` , takes time proportional to its
>   first argument xs, the implementation in terms of fold right in
>   flattenRight is more efficient than the fold left implementation in
>   flattenLeft . The problem is that flattenLeft(xss) copies the first
>   element list xss.head n − 1 times, where n is the length of the list
>   xss

So if list concatenation takes time proportional to its *first* argument, wouldn't that mean `flattenLeft` is the more efficient since its first argument is an empty list and `flattenRight`'s first argument is a list of unknown length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `foldLeft` is just an empty `List` at the beginning, that is, the `zero` for this fold.

As you fold all the `List`s onto one `List`, the `fold` builds intermediate lists with the partial result on each concatenation, which is then used as argument to the next concatenation. This intermediate result keeps getting bigger and bigger. On a `foldLeft`, this will be the first argument :

```
 def flattenLeft[T](xss: List[List[T]]) =
   (List[T]() /: xss) ((acc, xs) => acc ::: xs )
                      //^ this one
```

On the contrary, for a `foldRight` you build the result from the right, which means the intermediate result (the one that grows ) is the right one, which will be the second argument to the concatenation operation

```
def flattenRight[T](xss: List[List[T]]) =
   (xss :\ List[T]()) ((xs, acc) =>  xs ::: acc)
                            //^ this one gets bigger now
```

So, a `flattenRight` will take less time, since the first argument to concatenate doesn't grow as you progress.

Answer (score 2):

Flattening the lists by folding from the left proceeds as

```
[ [....] [....] [....] [....] [....] ]
  [....] 
  [...........] 
  [..................] 
  [.........................] 
  [................................]
```

and from the right as

```
[ [....] [....] [....] [....] [....] ]
                              [....] 
                       [...........]  
                [..................]  
         [.........................]  
  [................................]
```

When folding *n* lists from the left, each element in the first list is traced over *(n-1)* times; in the second list *(n-2)* times, etc. This is classic quadratic behaviour.

When folding from the right, each element is traced over exactly *once*, for the total operation's linear behaviour.